Route Fails with Specific Query Parameters (`code` and `state`)
I'm encountering an issue with react-router-dom in my React application. I have a route set up for /selects, which works fine unless I include both code and state query parameters.
For example, this route doesn't render anything at all:
http://localhost:3000/v2/something/selects?code=sdasdasdasdas&state=sdasdsadas

However, if I change one of the query parameter names, or pass only one query parameter, the route works as expected.
Additionally, if I use the code and state query parameters in other routes within the same app, like this:
http://localhost:3000/helloworld?code=something&state=somethingelse

it works without any issues.
I've tried creating a new React project with the same routing structure, and everything works fine in that setup.
Any ideas on why the route /selects is failing when both code and state are passed as query parameters in my current app? Could there be a conflict or something I'm missing? Any help is appreciated!
// Selects.tsx

const SelectAdAccount = () => {
  return <h1>Something</h1>;
};

export default SelectAdAccount;

Not getting any errors in console.

The problem will likely be in the component you are rendering on the /selects route which likely is handling said parameters in such a way that leads to a render error. Please edit the question to include the code for that component. Additionally, please check the browser dev tools console for errors, and edit your question with them if there are any.

I don't see any overt issue in the code you have shared. Please [edit] the post to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with, and any additional debugging details you may have already collected.

My bad, I have integrated Auth0 React SDK and that is causing the issue.
This snippet fixed the issue.
useEffect(() => {
    if (!isAuthenticated) {
      getAccessTokenSilently();
    }
  }, [isAuthenticated, getAccessTokenSilently]);


